# Use Field Formatter in Spring RestControllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I try to make a RestController use my custom formatter for a java.time.Duration, but I am not successful not knowing why. I have a simple Order entity, a OrderController and a DurationFormatter that should be applied for the conversion of the Duration typed fields of the Order from and to Strings. The Formatter is registered with a FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean in the Configuration class. This is the code:

```
public class Order {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotNull
    private String customerId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ZonedDateTime validFrom;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ZonedDateTime validTo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Duration maxDuration;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Duration actDuration;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("order")
public class OrderController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@RequestBody @Valid Order order) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/" + order.getId()).build().toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Order getExample() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setMaxDuration(Duration.ofHours(10));
        return order;
    }
}

public class DurationFormatter implements Formatter<Duration>{

    @Override
    public String print(Duration duration, Locale locale) {
        return new Long(duration.toHours()).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Duration parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return Duration.ofHours(Long.parseLong(text));
    }

}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean getFormattingConversionServiceFactory() {
        FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        Set<Formatter<?>> formatters = new HashSet<>();
        formatters.add(new DurationFormatter());
        factory.setFormatters(formatters);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

When I try to post an Order this is the error I get:

> at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@595e3818; line: 4, column:
>   30] (through reference chain:
>   com.sap.sptutorial.rest.Order["maxDuration"]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.Duration] from
>   String value ('67'); no single-String constructor/factory method

Can anybody suggest me the right way to apply formatters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatters have nothing to do with JSON deserialization. That's the task of `Jackson` in your case. It should be enough to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` to get support for the new Java 8 types.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. This is not clear from the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format. Anyway. This means I have to look into ways to adapt the default serialization of the jackson lib. Thank you!